# hide banner from innerpages - magento

Tags: javascript, magento

I want to hide a banner from inner pages but I need to display that in home page

I have put this banner in left-col.phtml

so i tried to identify the base url using javascript.if its in base url show the banner otherwise hide it

like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">

if([removed].pathname !="/")
{

var ele = document.getElementById("flashcontent");
ele.style.display = 'none';


}
else
{


}

</script>
```

but it doesnt work.anybody ahve an idea to do this.

Note: i dont have a home page in CMS>Pages.this is a purchased template

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check This code.

```
<?php
if($this->getUrl('') == $this->getUrl('*/*/*', array('_current'=>true, '_use_rewrite'=>true))):
    echo "Homepage";
else:
    echo "Not in Homepage";
endif;
?>
```

it would helpful to you.

Comment: Hi Prakash,

Thanks a lot :)